# How can I use the local variable of a self-define function in another self-def function in Python

Tags: python, function

I have written a function of sign_up in Python:

```
def sign_up():
    print('You choose to sign up: ')
    name = input('Please input your name: ')
    phone_number = input('Please input your phone number: ')
    code1 = str(input('Please input your code: '))
    code2 = str(input('Please input your code again to make sure right: '))

    while code1 != code2:
        print('Your two times-codes are not same, just try again: ')
        code1 = str(input('Please input your code: '))
        code2 = str(input('Please input your code again to make sure right: '))

    else:
        print('You have signed up successfully. Just wait to jump to the main page....')

    customer = {'name': name, 'phone_number': phone_number, 'code': code1}
    return
```

As you can see,I used a dictionary named 'customer' to store information of a customer.
My trouble is:

When I want to write function log_in() and I want to use dictionary 'customer' which was defined in function sign_up() to check whether the information user inputs is the same as in dictionary 'customer'.When I did that, the 'customer' got an error " Unresolved reference 'customer'" .What can I do to avoid it?Should I use a global variable?

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: For the purposes of learning, you probably could make it `global` (this is generally considered bad practice). A better solution would be to `return customer` to something that calls the function, and then pass that variable to  `log_in`. My spidey senses tell me that you're going to get tangled up very quickly if you are trying to maintain the logged in status of a user, though, as the code develops. It's perhaps a good time to look into persistence e.g. SQLite

Comment: Yes, you can make it global and then use it in every function you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your variable only exists in local scope (in function `sign_up()`).
The simplest way is to make your variable global.

```
def sign_up():
    print('You choose to sign up: ')
    name = input('Please input your name: ')
    phone_number = input('Please input your phone number: ')
    code1 = str(input('Please input your code: '))
    code2 = str(input('Please input your code again to make sure right: '))

    while code1 != code2:
        print('Your two times-codes are not same, just try again: ')
        code1 = str(input('Please input your code: '))
        code2 = str(input('Please input your code again to make sure right: '))

    else:
        print('You have signed up successfully. Just wait to jump to the main page....')

    global customer
    customer = {'name': name, 'phone_number': phone_number, 'code': code1}
    return
```

now you should be able to use `customer` wherever you want